# Rubymotion: adhoc provisioning profile along side developer provisioning profile

Tags: provisioning, rubymotion

With RubyMotion, you can specify a provisioning profile in your rake file like so:

```
app.provisioning_profile = './myprofile.mobileprovision'
```

Seeing that there is only one field for a provisioning profile, how can I configure my ad hoc distribution profile I use for testflight without overwriting the provisioning_profile field that contains my developer provisioning profile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an old question, but anybody looking for an answer:

```
app.release do
  app.provisioning_profile = './distribution.mobileprovision'
end

app.development do
  app.provisioning_profile = './development.mobileprovision'
end
```